# Identifying Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, stack-overflow

My code is below, I am trying to recursively call my binary search function but keep getting this Exception. I am trying to identify the source of the issue. Keep in mind i've excluded my code for creating the array list for simplicity and because i know they are functional.

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.math.*;
public class nickclass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

for(int i = 0; i <(int)listTest.size();i++)
   {
  binarySearchHelp(listTest2,(String)listTest.get(i),0,listTest2.size());
 }

void binarySearchHelp(ArrayList list, String value, int left, int right) {

    if (left > right)
        System.exit(0);

    int middle = (int) Math.floor(list.size()/2);

    if (((String) list.get(middle)).compareTo(value) == 0)
        System.out.println(list.get(middle));


    else if (((String) list.get(middle)).compareTo(value) > 0)
         binarySearchHelp(list, value, left, middle - 1);

    else
         binarySearchHelp(list, value, middle + 1, right);           

  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive call is never terminating (only when all memory is used) because `middle` is always the middle of the list, but it should be the *middle* between left and right:

```
middle = (left + right) / 2;
```

I would also check that the interval (left-right) is big enough to be divided or if the algorithm can stop... and System.exit is kind of brutal, you really want to stop the virtual machine without any message?

Comment: What is the better method for ending the recursive function?

Comment: it is an error if `left` is greater than `right`, so I would throw an Exception - `IllegalArgumentException` in that case

Comment: Yes but if it's equal to middle and I print it, how should I exit the function?

Comment: no need since the recursive call is inside the else and will not be executed - that is, the method just terminates. Or return the index of the found element - middle.

Comment: also remember to handle the case when left==right and the searched value is NOT in the list (assuming that is possible)